# Load csv into pandas dataframe from Pydrill Query

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pydrill

I am able to load a csv into pandas dataframe, but it is stuck in a list. How can I load directly into a pandas dataframe from Pydrill or unlist the pandas dataframe columns and data? I've tried unlisting and it puts everything into a list of a list.

I've used the to_dataframe(), but can't seem to find documentation on if I can use a delimeter. pd.dataframe doesn't work because of the Pydrill query.

```
reviews = drill.query("SELECT * FROM  hdfs.datasets.`titanic_ML/titanic.csv` LIMIT 1000", timeout=30)
print(reviews)
import pandas as pd
df2 = reviews.to_dataframe()
df2.rename(columns=df2.iloc[0])
headers = df2.iloc[0]
print(headers)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(df2.values[1:], columns=headers)
new_df.head()
```

The results cast everything into a list.

```
["pclass","sex","age","sibsp","parch","fare","embarked","survived"]

0   ["3","1","38.0","0","0","7.8958","1","0"]
1   ["1","1","42.0","0","0","26.55","1","0"]
2   ["3","0","9.0","4","2","31.275","1","0"]
3   ["3","1","27.0","0","0","7.25","1","0"]
4   ["1","1","41.0","0","0","26.55","1","0"]
```

I'd like to get everything into a normal pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was this:

it doesn't unlist the dataframe, but it's an alternate solution to the problem.

connect_str = "dbname='dbname' user='dsa_ro_user' 
conn = psycopg2.connect(connect_str) host='host database'

SQL = "SELECT * "
SQL += " FROM train"

df = pd.read_sql(SQL,conn)
df.head()

Answer (score 0):

Try using Table Functions as described in [O’Reily Text: Chapter 4. Querying Delimited Data](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-apache-drill/9781492032786/ch04.html). This will delimit the file and apply the first row to your columns. Note: because everything is being read as text, you may need to `cast` your values as floats if you want to do arithmetic in your `select` or `where`.

This should get you what you want:

```
sql="""
SELECT * 
FROM table(hdfs.datasets.`/titanic_ML/titanic.csv`(
    type => 'text', 
    extractHeader => true, 
    fieldDelimiter => ',')
) LIMIT 1000
"""

rows = drill.query(sql, timeout=30)

df = rows.to_dataframe()
df.head()
```